# dynamically loading images and display using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Here is the code

```js
        var URI= "getNDealsAjax.do";    


        var ajN = $.getJSON(URI, function(data) {

                var htmlStr = "";
                $.each(data, function(i,item){

                    htmlStr += "<li><a href='#'>";
                    htmlStr += "<img src='"+item.merchantImage+"'>";
                    htmlStr += "</a></li>";

                });
                alert("htmlStr: "+htmlStr);
                $('#ullink').html(htmlStr).trigger('create'); 
        });
```

```html
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="demo-page" class="my-page" data-url="demo-page">
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="ullink" data-inset="true">

    </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

I used .trigger('create'); for loading the html from javascript.

Please let me know if any idea how to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding just listview content then you need to do it a little bit different:

```
$('#ullink').html(htmlStr).listview('refresh');
```

or if that throws an error use this:

```
$('#ullink').html(htmlStr).listview().listview('refresh');
```

trigger('create') should be used to enhance whole content and as such it can be used correctly only on a **`data-role="content"`** DIV: